# How to prevent events in resource timeline from overlapping?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

I have a list of events with weekly intervals (e.g. 6–12 May 2022, 13–19 May 2022, etc). When the slot duration is also weekly and the slot interval is misaligned, the calendar display the events in a "zig-zag" pattern:

[image]

Is there any settings in the fullcalendar api that prevents this and "rounds down" the events to fit the slot like below:

[image]

I'd rather not process the events one by one because the events duration can be weekly, fortnightly, monthly and the slot duration can vary as well. This would make it difficult to process the different permutations of event and slot duration.

I have tried setting `eventOverlap` and `slotEventOverlap` to false but the "zig-zag" pattern still persists.

This is the minimal reproducible example:

```
const MyCalendar = () => {
  const start = new Date(2022, 4, 6);
  const end = new Date(2022, 4, 12);

  const resources = [{ id: "1", title: "random weekly" }];
  const events = Array(8)
    .fill()
    .map((_, index) => ({
      id: index,
      title: "random weekly",
      resourceId: "1",
      allDay: true,
      start: moment(start)
        .add(7 * index, "days")
        .toDate(),
      end: moment(end)
        .add(7 * index, "days")
        .toDate(),
      overlap: false,
    }));

  return (
    <FullCalendar
      plugins={[resourceTimelinePlugin]}
      resources={resources}
      events={events}
      slotEventOverlap={false}
      eventOverlap={false}
      initialView="quarter"
      views={{
        quarter: {
          type: "resourceTimeline",
          slotDuration: { weeks: 1 },
          visibleRange: { start: new Date(2022, 3, 1), end: new Date(2022, 6, 1) },
        },
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve the problem in the backend. Here is an example with nodejs and momentjs library:

```
const moment = require('moment');


function checkEventOverlap(allEvents, data) {
    for (const event of allEvents) {
        const dataStart = moment(data.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        const dataEnd = moment(data.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        const eStart = moment(event.start).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
        const eEnd = moment(event.end).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

        if (
            moment(dataStart).isBetween(eStart, eEnd) ||
            moment(dataEnd).isBetween(eStart, eEnd) ||
            moment(eStart).isBetween(dataStart, dataEnd) ||
            moment(eEnd).isBetween(dataStart, dataEnd)
        ) {
            return { error: "You can't create more than 2 events in one timeline" };
        }
    }

    return "You can add your event";
}
    const data = { //your new event
        start: "01.01.2024",
        end: "02.01.2024"
    }

    const dataTwo = { //your new event
        start: "01.01.2024",
        end: "07.01.2024"
    }
    const allEvents = [
        {
            start: "05.01.2024",
            end: "07.01.2024"
        },
        {
            start: "02.01.2024",
            end: "03.01.2024"
        },
        {
            start: "03.01.2024",
            end: "04.01.2024"
        }
    ]

    console.log(checkEventOverlap(allEvents, data))
// response is "You can add your event"

    console.log(checkEventOverlap(allEvents, dataTwo))
// response is "{ error: "You can't create more than 2 events in one timeline" }"
```